# 9 (7.4v) Li-ion rechargeable battery maximium drain current?

Tags: batteries, discharge

Battery such like these:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B078JMHHF8/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B078JMHHF8)

I found no official information about continuous discharge rate.

Li-ion should have a large discharge rate (10C), however, I have heard otherwise for these "9v" Li-ion batteries (0.5C?)

Have anyone tested the maximum discharge rate for these? If it is truly 0.5 C, then why? (being Li-ion, shouldn't it be 10C?)

Comment: I actually bought it and tested it, it is indeed ( roughly) 550mah.

Comment: And it could ( at least) discharge 1a

Answer (score 1):

No, it is wrong to assume that every Li-Ion battery has 10C discharge rate. As a matter of fact, only specialized batteries for Radio-Controlled toys have high discharge rates, 10C, 15C and above. Or industrial automotive/bike batteries. Most batteries that are designed for long-term operations (as smoke detectors) use more conservative design materials, thicker membrane separators, etc. and are optimized for low discharge rates.

Looking at the battery, it seems that it has an actual capacity of about 550 mAh, and voltage 8.4V ([**2 Li-Ion cells is series, typical**](https://lygte-info.dk/info/BatteryDisassembly9VLiIon%20UK.html)). I wouldn't charge it at more than 200-300 mA.

The charger, however, reads "8.4 V 500 mA" as per customer's questions-answers at Amazon, which implies the use of ordinary USB port. And the marketing materials say "charges 3 batteries in 3 hours". This leads to the following calculations/speculations. 3 hours with 8.4 V at 0.5 A is just 12.6 Watts-hours. Which means (assuming ideal converter) that each battery has the capacity of 4.2 Wh. At 8.4 initial volts (and likely 7.6 running volts) it makes the battery capacity as about 550 mAh, which is likely it's real capacity. So, I would say that the discharge rate of about 55 mA is the right one for this battery.  You probably can get more, 200-500 mA, but the capacity will degrade.

EDIT: From some reviewers, this "9-V" battery is the best, made by iPowerUS. Here are [**test data**](https://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries9V/iPowerUS%209V%20Pro%20520mAh%20%28Silver%29%20UK.html) for it. Discharge current is 500 mA max. Internal resistance - under 450 mOhms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have discharged a battery, very similar to the ones you mention:

[image: Li-Ion e³ battery]

[Full test results here](http://anrieff.net/batterytest/details/others/e3-LiIon-9V-en.html).

This has been advertised as 600 mAh, but I found it was around 530-540 mAh at C/10 discharge. I also tried at C/2 discharge (330 mA), and it had virtually the same capacity.

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not be 10C.

Li-Ion comes in 3 types:

- high capacity, normal current (up to 2A discharge, usually 1A) - they exist up to 3400mAh currently.
- medium capacity, high current (the 10A ones) - they usually are around 2150mAh capacity values
- low capacity, very high current (25+A) - they are the power tools batteries, usually 1300-1600mAh capacity (2000 in certain cases)

Given that 9V batteries were designed for low consumption applications, there is absolutely no reason to use more expensive Li-ion tech; the normal one suffices.

From practical testing (I can't say the exact models now or how original they were) a few months ago I tested the discharge rates of 2 brands of 9V li-ion batteries and the safe values were around 240mA. Anything more starts to have bad effects, including overheating.